# Google feed API causing page to go blank

Tags: javascript, load, feed

This may sound ridiculous, but is there a reason that something as simple as calling a single line of code would force my webpage to go blank?

Here is the line of code that is forcing the page to become blank

```
google.load("feeds", "1");
```

I am trying to simply load the Google Feed API in order to parse the google news feed and have access to the images, etc.

I came across this link earlier: [Why does google.load cause my page to go blank?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519673/why-does-google-load-cause-my-page-to-go-blank)

I have attempted to load the feed api via a setTimeOut as has been suggested in various other sources but it has the exact same effect unfortunately.

I should also mention that in both cases I have added this code to the top of my document ready function.

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on this? Still haven't found any proper reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just a comment, i cant comment still, as your linked says its not use a timeout to fix it, the timeout could be the cause or something like it. Also, the "fix" with the timeout or something like it after the dom has loaded is to adding it an empty callback.
You can see the answers in that post you linked.
(i add this answer so people that might find this go to the correct linked post, good luck)