# google jsapi don't load in Drupal 7

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-7, jsapi

i'm developing in Drupal 7. i've created a custom module with reports where a i'd like  add charts with google jsapi.
I've call this api:

```
drupal_add_js('https://www.google.com/jsapi');
```

Then in mymodule.js used the next dummy js:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 function drawChart() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
     ['Work',     1],
     ['Eat',      2],
     ['Commute',  2],
     ['Watch TV', 2],
     ['Sleep',    7]
   ]);

   var options = {
     title: 'My Daily Activities',
     pieHole: 0.4,
   };

   var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
   chart.draw(data, options);
 }
```

This dummy goes to mymodule.admin.inc in:

```
<div id="donutchart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

The problem is when the site charge the jsapi, all site simply keeps on charging and nothing happen.

I've been following this tutorial  https://drupal.org/node/1808654.

I hope someone can help me to solve this problem, Thanks for respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When including external hosted javascript files, you need to specify that it is `external` when calling the `drupal_add_js` function. When not specifying this argument, Drupal will try to load it on the file system (which doesn't exists).

```
drupal_add_js('https://www.google.com/jsapi', 'external');
```

**Update**

It seems that you are experiencing the [blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519673/why-does-google-load-cause-my-page-to-go-blank) problem. Could you try with the following javascript code, I've changed the callback definition passing it directly through the load function.

```
google.load("visualization", "1", { 'callback': 'drawChart', packages: ["corechart"] });

function drawChart() {
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
     ['Work',     1],
     ['Eat',      2],
     ['Commute',  2],
     ['Watch TV', 2],
     ['Sleep',    7]
   ]);

   var options = {
     title: 'My Daily Activities',
     pieHole: 0.4
   };

   var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('donutchart'));
   chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, already changed this line but the problem persist and firebug from mozilla shows this:  
If <script> tags have a "type" attribute, it should equal "text/javascript" or "application/javascript". Also scripts must be parsable (syntactically correct).

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible solution. It seems to be problem with the callback declaration.

Comment: Great! The site works again and the chart displayed,thanks a lot! the problem was fixed!
Gracias amigo!