# Unresponsive button after calling javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using this js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/iansan5653/7EPjH/17/

My problem is with the buttons at the top. They should display information in the text areas. In my browser, the buttons blank the page. Executing the same onclick code in the in console works, however. What am I doing wrong?

Some code left out for brevity

```
   var abstractlog = "1 0 c\n 2 0 b\n 3 0 a\n 4 0 d\n 1 1 f\n 2 1 b\n 3 1 a\n 4 1 e\n 1 2 f\n 2 2 b\n 3 2 a\n 4 2 d";
var abstractargs = "-r ^(?<TYPE>),(?<TIME>),(?<trace>)\n 2 -m \\k<trace>" ;

var browserlog = "64.163.76.74, cache-page, 0\n 164.163.76.74, retrieve-page, 9\n 164.163.76.74, cache-image, 18\n 164.163.76.74, retrieve-image, 39\n 164.163.76.74, quit, 160 \n --\n 237.250.28.190, cache-page, 0\n 237.250.28.190, retrieve-page, 17\n 237.250.28.190, cache-image, 34\n 237.250.28.190, retrieve-image, 104 \n 237.250.28.190, quit, 274 \n --\n 130.78.242.94, cache-page, 0\n 130.78.242.94, retrieve-page, 9\n 130.78.242.94, cache-image, 118 \n 130.78.242.94, retrieve-image, 140 \n 130.78.242.94, quit, 162 \n --\n 177.176.181.25, cache-page, 0\n 177.176.181.25, retrieve-page, 17\n 177.176.181.25, cache-image, 136 \n 177.176.181.25, retrieve-image, 204 \n 177.176.181.25, quit, 272 \n --\n 195.88.181.89, cache-image, 0\n 195.88.181.89, retrieve-image, 27\n 195.88.181.89, quit, 54\n --\n 153.98.187.29, cache-image, 0\n 153.98.187.29, retrieve-image, 62\n 153.98.187.29, quit, 124";
var browserargs = "-r (?<ip>) .+:(?<DTIME>.+)\\] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /(?<TYPE>.+)\" -m \\k<ip>" ;

var connectionlog =   "\"19.38.218.11 [31/May/2014:31200.0] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /test-bandwidth\"\n 19.38.218.11 [31/May/2014:31202.0] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /narrowband\"\n 19.38.218.11 [31/May/2014:31205.7] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /query\"\n 19.38.218.11 [31/May/2014:31208.9] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /query\"\n 19.38.218.11 [31/May/2014:31209.7] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /report-normal\"\n 95.39.21.28 [31/May/2014:31200.3] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /test-bandwidth\"\n 95.39.21.28 [31/May/2014:31202.3] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /narrowband\"\n 95.39.21.28 [31/May/2014:31206.0] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /query\"\n 95.39.21.28 [31/May/2014:31206.8] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /report-normal\"\n 210.82.199.247 [31/May/2014:31200.1] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /test-bandwidth\"\n 210.82.199.247 [31/May/2014:31200.8] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /broadband\"\n 210.82.199.247 [31/May/2014:31202.1] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /query\"\n 210.82.199.247 [31/May/2014:31208.3] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /query\"\n 210.82.199.247 [31/May/2014:31208.8] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /report-abnormal\"\n 130.78.242.94 [31/May/2014:31200.1] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /test-bandwidth\"\n 130.78.242.94 [31/May/2014:31200.7] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /broadband\"\n 130.78.242.94 [31/May/2014:31201.9] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /query\"\n 130.78.242.94 [31/May/2014:31208.0] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /query\"\n 130.78.242.94 [31/May/2014:31208.4] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /report-abnormal\"\n 38.151.1.182 [31/May/2014:31200.2] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /test-bandwidth\"\n 38.151.1.182 [31/May/2014:31200.8] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /broadband\"\n 38.151.1.182 [31/May/2014:31202.0] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /query\"\n 38.151.1.182 [31/May/2014:31203.3] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /query\"\n 38.151.1.182 [31/May/2014:31203.8] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /report-normal\"\n 37.161.90.108 [31/May/2014:31200.2] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /test-bandwidth\"\n 37.161.90.108 [31/May/2014:31200.9] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /broadband\"\n 37.161.90.108 [31/May/2014:31202.2] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /query\"\n 37.161.90.108 [31/May/2014:31203.6] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /query\"\n 37.161.90.108 [31/May/2014:31204.7] \"GET HTTP/1.1 /report-normal\"";
var connectionargs = "-r (?<ip>.+), (?<TYPE>.+), (?<DTIME>.+) -s ^--$";
 var logstring;
 var argstring;

function writeAbstractModel() {
       logstring =  abstractlog ;
       argstring = abstractargs;K
}

function writeBrowserModel() {
    logstring = browserlog ;
    argstring = browserargs;
}

function writeConnectionModel() {
    logstring = connectionlog ;
    argstring = connectionargs;
}

function write() {
    $("#logtext").val(logstring);
    $("#args").val(argstring);
}

<button id="abstractform" onclick="writeAbstractModel(); write(); data = abc_model;">Abstract Example </button>
    <button id="bandwithform" onclick="writeBrowserModel(); write(); data = test_bandwith_model;">Bandwith Example</button>
    <button type="browserform" onclick="writeConnectionModel(); write(); data = browser_model;"> Browser Example</button>
```

Comment: @summea if you clear your console and then run the fiddle again (without refreshing the page) you'll see the error is on jiddle load on on the iframe containing the code load.. so i dont think that is the problem.. from what i can see.. clicking the `button` actually removes the `<body>` element from the page.. :O

Comment: For later: you may want to replace the code in your question above with the code from your Fiddle...

Comment: Did the answer below help your situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is a cool project!

One of the main issues of this code seems to be related to how `google.load` [uses a document.write() call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9520427/1167750) when adding code/scripts to an HTML page.

But there is *[at least one way](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/fMKJcyA2yyI)* of getting something like this *"click button to display visualizations"* process to work as intended:

### Step 1

Try adding a general "document ready" section in your JavaScript, and moving your `google.load` into it, like this:

```
// prepare click event for "Draw Chart" button
$(document).ready(function() {
    google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge'], callback: function () {
        $('#draw_chart').click(function () {
            chart();
        });
    }});
});
```

### Step 2

Adjust the `drawChart()` call from earlier and place it inside the inner `$.getJSON()` function, like this:

```
$.getJSON(url,
    function(data){
        pressure = data.value.items[0].data[1].parameters.pressure.value;
        temperature = data.value.items[0].data[1].parameters.temperature[0].value;
        humidity = data.value.items[0].data[1].parameters.humidity.value;

        // then call drawChart knowing that we have some sort of data
        drawChart();
    }
);
```

### Step 3

Finally, update the HTML button id so that it can be "activated" to know what to do once clicked by user, like this:

```
<button id="draw_chart">Draw Chart</button>
```

### Full Code Example

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

    var pressure;
    var temperature;
    var humidity;

    function chart() {
        var url = 'http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=97c669df9c4795db96b39188000c1998&_render=json&lat=26.6403&lon=-81.8725';
        $.getJSON(url,
            function(data){
                pressure = data.value.items[0].data[1].parameters.pressure.value;
                temperature = data.value.items[0].data[1].parameters.temperature[0].value;
                humidity = data.value.items[0].data[1].parameters.humidity.value;

                // then call drawChart knowing that we have some sort of data
                drawChart();
            }
        );
      }

    function drawChart() {

        pressure = eval(pressure);
        var barData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Label', 'Value'],
            ['C/Precip', pressure]
            ]);

        var barOptions = {
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            redFrom: 28,
            redTo: 29,
            yellowFrom: 29,
            yellowTo: 30,
            greenFrom: 30,
            greenTo: 31,
            min: 28,
            max: 31,
            majorTicks: ["28","29","30","31"],
            minorTicks: 10
        };

        var barChart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('barometer_div'));
        barChart.draw(barData, barOptions);

        temperature = eval(temperature);
        var thermData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Label', 'Value'],
            ['Temp (F)', temperature]
            ]);

        var thermOptions = {
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            redFrom: 80,
            redTo: 120,
            yellowFrom: 0,
            yellowTo: 40,
            yellowColor: '0099FF',
            greenFrom: 40,
            greenTo: 80,
            min: 0,
            max: 120,
            majorTicks: ["0","10","20","30","40","50","60","70","80","90","100","110","120"],
            minorTicks: 10
        };
        var thermChart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('thermometer_div'));
        thermChart.draw(thermData, thermOptions);

        humidity = eval(humidity);
        var humidData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['Label', 'Value'],
            ['Humidity', humidity]
            ]);

        var humidOptions = {
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            yellowFrom: 10,
            yellowTo: 40,
            greenFrom: 40,
            greenTo: 70,
            redColor: '0099FF',
            redFrom: 70,
            redTo: 100,
            min: 10,
            max: 100,
            majorTicks: ["10","20","30","40","50","60","70","80","90","100"],
            minorTicks: 10
        };
        var humidChart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('humidostat_div'));
        humidChart.draw(humidData, humidOptions);
    }

    // prepare click event for "Draw Chart" button
    $(document).ready(function() {
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['gauge'], callback: function () {
            $('#draw_chart').click(function () {
                chart();
            });
        }});
    });

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="draw_chart">Draw Chart</button>
    <div id='barometer_div'></div>
    <div id='thermometer_div'></div>
    <div id='humidostat_div'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Code Example Demo

[(as a fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/7EPjH/68/)

### Notes

- More information about this sort of issue and other workarounds can be found on [this Google Groups thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/fMKJcyA2yyI).*
- <s>At present, the gauges slowly shrink in size over time when continuously reloaded...</s> This is fixed by specifying *both* a *width* and a *height* for each visualization. *See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/TXQthT6qaME) for more information.*